# Did Xamarin forms supports Bing maps insted of Google map native control?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, bing-maps

We have an requirement for showing Bing maps view in Xamarin forms app for Android and iOS both.
 We have done the integration of Google maps for both platforms with the help of 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#Using_Xaml
and 
https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.

I neither found any documentation that Bing maps supported on Android and iOS nor any thing says it did not support.

So How can I get documentation to integrate Bing maps in my Xamarin forms Android and iOS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms supports *Bing Maps* only for UWP not for android or iOS. There is not official announcement or SDK's are available to do so. If you wish to add *Bing Maps* do it for UWP project. For Android need to have GoogleAPI's keys. Along with iOS project you can go either `apple map's` or `google map's`.
To have detailed information go through below articles

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-google-and-bing-maps-using-xamarin-forms/

https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/how-to-integrate-bing-map-in-android/