# Do Xamarin.Forms support Bing Maps for android or iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, bing-maps, .net-standard

I want to use Bing Map in Xamarin.Forms for Android and iOS. I came to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300656/did-xamarin-forms-supports-bing-maps-insted-of-google-map-native-control) which says that Bing map can not be used in Xamarin.forms for android and iOS but it seems old post. Can some one help me how Bing Map can be used in Xamarin.Forms in android and iOS or still it does not suppport?

Comment: Bing Maps SDK is only available in native Android and iOS, And for Xamarin.Forms would require creating a binding library and writing custom renderers from scratch.
check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/sdk-native/ .